# PhpStorm: multiple projects with common core

Tags: phpstorm, web-deployment

Due to security reasons, I have to split one project to divisions (client, admin, ...), and deploy them to different web servers. These divisions have one common script base, but each division has its own functions. As an IDE I use PhpStorm.

The question: what is the best way to organize project's structure and settings, so the common core part will be visible for IDE indexing in all project's divisions, but at the same time, being maintained from a single project (perhaps, standalone)?

In Java you can do lib jar files for further linking in various projects.
But how it can be done in PHP?

Comment: If you plan to edit it: you can do it as an Additional Content Root -- will be shown as a separate node in a Project View (in addition to the actual project code). If no plans to edit: you may add it as a "Include Path" entry (for PHP code mainly). P.S. Symlinks can also be an option here. PHP code can also be included as a separate composer package (custom repo/source).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks! Additional Content Root is the best way, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of how to reference extra PHP code in a project.

**If you plan to actively edit such extra code in the same project** (and want to see their TODOs, code inspection warnings, include references in code refactoring etc):

- You can just add it as an additional Content Root: `Settings/Preferences | Directories`. Folder added this way will be treated as a part of the project itself and will be shown as a separate node in the Project View panel (just as the main code, which is a Content Root as well).
- Or you can open 2nd project while 1st one is already opened and when asked, just chose "Attach":

  [image]

  It's not going to be full 2 projects in one frame, more like something in between attaching Content Root and having 2 projects opened in separate frames.

  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/opening-multiple-projects.html
- Simple symlink will also do the job (but you need to place it somewhere in a project, e.g. `PROJECT_ROOT/libs/my_symlinked_code`). You then will need to provide a path mapping for that folder for debugger (if you will debug it of course) as PHP/Xdebug works with "final/resolved path" while IDE works with the path as is.

**If you do not need to actively edit that extra code in the same window** (and ignore any TODOs, code inspection warnings and other inspection results etc):

- Do it as a composer package then? Composer can use custom sources (e.g. GitHub repo or a folder on a local filesystem).
- Just add the path to that folder as a "Include Path" at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP --> Include Path tab`. Code referenced this way is meant for 3rd party libraries (the code that you just use but not edit, e.g. framework code, your send mail/ORM library etc). Composer packages will also be included here by default.

  [image]

  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php.html#include-path-tab